# A program to merge two lists into one

Tags: java, arrays, merge, jgrasp

I have to merge these two lists. This is my uncompleted coding program so far. I cannot make any further progress. I need to help to finish this assignment. The merged list should contain all of the provided number. Also, if you wish, can you leave a detail solving process for my studying?

```
public class Lab18bvst
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] jsaList1 = {101, 105, 115, 125, 145, 165, 175, 185, 195, 225, 235, 275, 305, 315, 325, 335, 345, 355, 375, 385};
        int[] jsaList2 = {110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 270, 280, 320, 350, 400};

        Array list1 = new Array(jsaList1,"List #1");
        Array list2 = new Array(jsaList2,"List #2");
        Array list3 = new Array("Merged List");

        list3.merge(list1,list2);

        list1.display();
        list2.display();
        list3.display();

    }

}
class Array
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    private int size;
    private String listName;

    public Array(String ln)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        size = 0;
        listName = ln;
    }

    public Array(int[] jsArray, String ln)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        size = jsArray.length;
        listName = ln;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            list.add( new Integer( jsArray[j] ));
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + listName + ":\n");
        System.out.println(list + "\n");
    }

    public void merge(Array that, Array theOther)
   {
      int thatIndex, theOtherIndex;
      thatIndex = theOtherIndex = 0;

      for (int j = 1; j <= that.size + theOther.size; j++)
      {
         if (thatIndex >= that.size)
         {
            while(theOtherIndex < theOther.size)
            {
               this.list.add(theOther.list.get(theOtherIndex));
               theOtherIndex++;
            }
         }
         else if (theOtherIndex >= theOther.size)
         {
            while(thatIndex < that.size)
            {
               this.list.add(theOther.list.get(thatIndex));
               thatIndex++;
            }
         }
         else if

         else

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: I need 1 million dollar ASAP!!!1!

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: I need a pony ASAP!!one

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer PONIES!!! More important than 1 million dollar. I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way of joining 2 lists

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.addAll(listOne);
newList.addAll(listTwo);
```

Comment: it's a concatenation, not exactly a merge (you dont eliminate duplicates).

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Make `newList` a `Set` type and it will.